# Aura component for building queries?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I remember seeing an aura component for allowing the user to build a query e.g. **_ where ____ order by _** type thing. I can no longer find it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such "out of the box" element that does this (at least as of Winter '20 and all prior releases), but there are plenty of open-source varieties you can look at, for example, [this one](https://github.com/tsalb/sfdc-lightning-service-components) (disclaimer, not my own, I do not guarantee suitability for any particular purpose).